# Integrate Einstein Bot with Google Cloud

Tags: salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-einstein, jfeinstein

I have a requirement where I need to integrate Google Cloud with Einstein Bot such that Google Cloud can be used as a data source for the Bot instead of salesforce.
Can we use Einstein Bot Platform API for the purpose?
If yes, how can we do it?
If not, what's the alternative?

I have done R&D on this but I'm unable to find a suitable solution for this one.